# UIButton appearance setBackgroundColor effecting navigation bar now after update

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

Xcode or iOS update has made the following code below function differently because now the navigation bar button background has a background color, unlike previously.  Any fix?  I want all buttons to have the same global color, but now it effects the navigation bar buttons which I dont want.  I would like it transparent like before.

```
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:[Helper getColor:self.application.color]];
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this particular UIButton is inside a UINavigationBar you could try applying a second specific appearance to 'override' the first general appearance set.
For example calling specifically,

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil]
       setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:state barMetrics:metrics];
```

after you call,

```
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:[Helper getColor:self.application.color]];
```

To override the general with the specific.

Docs Link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance

Comment: Life saver...I went this route though `[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setBackgroundColor:nil];`